# How can I serialize this .NET Collection item?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, xml-serialization

I'm trying to xml serialize a POCO view data class into xml. It serializes, but incorrectly generates some xml.

eg. (current result .. not the one I'm after)

```
<ReviewListViewData>
    <reviews>
        <review>....</review>
        ...
    </reviews>
</ReviewListViewData>
```

I'm trying to get (notice how I've removed the *bad* root node?) ...

```
<reviews>
    <review>....</review>
    ...
</reviews>
```

Class is defined as...

```
public class ReviewListViewData
{
    [XmlArray("reviews")]
    [XmlArrayItem("review")]
    public ReviewViewData[] Reviews { get; set; }
}
```

and here's a sample way it's called in an ASP.NET MVC ActionMethod :-

```
var reviewListViewData = GetReviewListViewData(...);
return XmlResult(reviewListViewData);  // (XmlResult referenced from MVCContrib).
```

anyone have any ideas, please?

Comment: do u need to serialize object without "bad" root node of  ReviewListViewData?

Comment: Yes please. I don't want that *bad* root node 'ReviewListViewData'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
[XmlRoot("reviews")]
public class ReviewListViewData
{
    [XmlElement("review")]
    public ReviewViewData[] Reviews { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try decorating the class ReviewListViewData with `[XmlRoot("reviews")]` instead of the XmlArray?